# Making a POST request with react native

Tags: json, react-native, post, httprequest

I am working on a mobile application with react native. I'm pretty new to this and I am unable to figure out how to make a proper POST HTTP request to send data to an API. I was given the following example:

POST https://website.org/api/records/?units=12&title=Volunteering&recordDate=07/10/2018&requirementId=3&serviceType=campus

POST /devapi/records/?access_token=[...] HTTP/1.1

Host: website.org

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

units=12331&title=test&date=07/10/2018&requirementId=3&isInternal=1&serviceType=campus

---

*Success looks like:*

{

"recordId": 63, 
  "units": 2, 
  "name": "Bob", 
  "success": true

}

---

*Errors look like:*

{

"message": "You must enter a date for this record.", 
  "error": -2

}

My current solution is the following:

```
postRecord() {
   const input = {
     units: this.state.units,
     title: this.state.title,
     date: this.convertToUnix(this.state.date),
     requirementId: this.props.navigation.state.params.requirementId,
     isInternal: this.state.differentiateExternal,
     serviceType: this.state.type
   };

   const params = this.props.screenProps.navigation.state.params;
   const accessToken = params ? params.currstate.accessToken : null;
   const searchParams = Object.keys(input).map((key) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(input[key])}`).join('&');

   console.log('searchParams', searchParams);

   return fetch('https://webiste.org/devapi/records/?access_token=' + accessToken=[...] HTTP/1.1, {
     method: 'POST',
     header: {
       'Content-length': '86',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
     body: input.units + input.title + input.date + input.requirementId + input.isInternal + input.serviceType
   })
   .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       console.log('the response is:', responseJson);
       if (responseJson.success === 'true') {
         Alert.alert(
          'Record created successfully',
          [
            {
            text: 'Ok',
            style: 'cancel',
            onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('RequirementRecordScreen')
            }
          ]
        );
       } else if (responseJson.error === -2) {
         Alert.alert(
           'There was an error creating the record',
           responseJson.message,
           [
             {
             text: 'Ok',
             style: 'cancel',
             onPress: () => console.log('Cancel xDDDD')
           }
         ],
       );
       }
     });
 }
```

On a test run my `console.log()` returns:

searchParams units=3&title=test%20test%20test&date=1534402800&requirementId=3&isInternal=0&serviceType=nation

Then a JSON response error saying that I need to enter a number of 'units' is always returned. How can I modify this to make it work properly?

Comment: You should contact with backend team. Maybe you are using wrong date param

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right variables in your request

```
return fetch('https://website.org/devapi/records/?access_token=' + accessToken, {
 method: 'POST',
 header: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 },
 body: searchInput
```

})

Answer (score 0):

```
 fetch('https://webiste.org/devapi/records/?access_token=' + accessToken=[...] HTTP/1.1',{
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  },
  body: input.units + input.title + input.date + input.requirementId + input.isInternal + input.serviceType
}).then((response)=>response.json()).
then((responseJson)=>{    
  if(resppnseJson==='Data Matched')
  {
    alert(responseJson);
  }else{
    alert(responseJson);
  }
})
.catch((error)=>{console.error(error)});
```

you can make a POST request by this way

Answer (score 0):

The [Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/network/) (regardless of whether you are using it or not for your RN project) recommends using Fetch, however, Fetch with `method: 'POST'` as a field sometimes doesn't work for certain header reasons and I personally have had bugs with it in the past when I don't put in `credentials: 'include'` as an argument.

```
axios.post(url, { userData: JSON.stringify(userData), oauth_provider:"google" })
.then(response => { 
    console.log("POST RESPONSE: " , JSON.stringify(response));
    // alert(JSON.stringify(response))
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("ERROR RESPONSE: " , JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

I recommend using the `axios` library. All you need to do is:

1. `npm install axios` in your project folder
2. `import axios from "axios"` at the header of your component/file
3. Utilize in your project -- I put a snippet I use below.

Additional considerations when posting to a domain is that it allows access from this URL, if you are posting to an API then use these headers at the top of your PHP file.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

The `*` can be replaced with your URL name. If you do use this method in your PHP file be sure to protect your file be using an auth key that you set yourself.